# ANT read a filename and insert that in a tag in the same file

Tags: javascript, ant

I want to use an ANT build, or possibly javascript, to do this:

```
For each file in a directory,
   read the filename.
   insert the filename into an xml tag inside the same file.
```

For example, let's say a file named `File_Name_One.txt`, has content that includes `<title>fileName-one</title>`. This content would be changed to `<title>File_Name_One</title>` instead.

It needs to cycle through all the files and replace what's in the `<title>` tag with the current correct filename, minus the extension.

I can handle the replaceregexp tasks needed to replace what's in the `<title>` tags, but not sure how to read and load the filename, and then how to insert this in the file it came from. I think maybe pathconvert would be part of how to do it, but I don't know how.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to scan directory searching for files or you have file names provided inside **File_Name_One.txt**??

Check [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) library. There are few nice tasks like [PropertyRegex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) or [Foreach](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) that you can use it...

If you want to scan files in directory try following code:

```
<property name="nl" value="${line.separator}"/>
<target name="test1">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <foreach target="gogogo" param="theFile">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" casesensitive="yes">
          <include name="**.*"/>
        </fileset>
      </foreach>
</target>

<target name="gogogo">
    <echo message="${theFile}"/>
    <concat append="true" destfile="out.txt">&lt;title&gt;${theFile}&lt;/title&gt;${nl}</concat>
</target>
```

Sample content of **out.txt** is:

```
<title>C:\workspace\.project</title>
<title>C:\workspace\TestANT.xml</title>
<title>C:\workspace\out3.txt</title>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris -- I want to scan a directory of files and read the actual filenames, not a list of filenames. If a file is named `File.txt`, then inside that same file I want to end up with `<title>File</title>` as part of the content. If a file is named `File2.txt` then inside **that** file I want to have `<title>File2</text>` The title elements exist already, for each document (each file), I want to replace what's inside the title tags. I had done something similar to what you have, using ant-contrib, it's the part about inserting each filename, as a property, into each file that I can't get.